# USB-TTL problem connected to my UART-WIFI module help!

Tags: serial, wireless, uart, ttl

A question is one to regulate that there warms up very much the chip of my usb-ttl that this feeding to my module uart-wifi as sample in the figure. That can be the problem helps.

[image]

PL-2303HX
[image]

Tlg10ua03 Uart-wifi
[image]

This way connect both modules:
[image]

Comment: Please post your question in English.

Comment: <clairvoyant>swapped RxD and TxD</clairvoyant> although I doubt that would really account for much warming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PL-2303HX Datasheet](http://www.prolific.com.tw/UserFiles/files/ds_pl2303HXD_v1_4_4.pdf) doesn't seem very clear on the amount of current that the on-chip regulator can handle but according to the [TLG10UA03 Datasheet](http://www.hed.com.cn/UpFile/File/201110171426488439.pdf) which is written in Chinese it appears the module has a typical current draw of 300mA. Most chips like the PL-2303 use a linear regulator so you'll be dissipating around 510mW plus what the converter itself uses so it's enough to make it feel warm. That leaves a few possibilities:

- You may not have a problem at all. For example see [Why is my Arduino Ethernet shield getting hot?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37623/why-is-my-arduino-ethernet-shield-getting-hot) You might want to measure the temperature to see what it is although if the PL-2303 isn't designed to source that much current you might still run into problems.
- If you want to be on the safe side another option would be to use the 5V output from the module that comes straight from the USB port along with a 3.3V regulator between the boards. That could either be a switching step-down regulator (many are available on e-bay) or a larger linear regular that can dissipate more heat.

Having said that the PL-2303 does have a way to request 500mA from the USB port which wouldn't make much sense if it wasn't capable of delivering that amount, so my best guess would be it's not really a problem.